# Angular string interpolation - Render \n

Tags: angular, textarea, string-interpolation

I wrote the following form:

```
<form [formGroup]="newNewsForm" novalidate>
        <md-select placeholder="Thème" formControlName="tag">
          <md-option *ngFor="let sport of [{id:'running', name:'running'}, {id: 'golf', name:'golf'}]" [value]="sport.id">
            {{sport.name}}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>

        <md-input-container class="full-width">
          <input mdInput placeholder="Titre" formControlName="title">
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container class="full-width">
          <textarea mdInput placeholder="Contenu" formControlName="content"></textarea>
        </md-input-container>
      </form>
```

I want to display a real-time preview to the user so I wrote the following:

```
<md-card class="full-width">

      <md-card-title>{{ newNewsForm?.value?.title }}</md-card-title>
      <md-card-subtitle *ngIf="newNewsForm?.value?.tag">#{{ newNewsForm?.value?.tag }}</md-card-subtitle>
      <md-card-content>
        <p>
           {{ newNewsForm?.value?.content }}
        </p>
      </md-card-content>

      <md-card-actions></md-card-actions>

    </md-card>
```

Everything works well except the use of carriage return character.

If I write the following into the textarea:
First Line,
Second Line

It is display a one single line into the preview: First Line, Second Line.

I tried with [innerHtml] unsuccessfully.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: carriage return character is done in HTML using <br/>

Comment: Can you post the code for the `<md-card-content>` component?

Comment: alright @RadouaneROUFID but I can't ask my user to type <br/> in is text

Comment: @skone it is tier code from AngularMaterial provided by Google. But fyi I try to put the <p> element directly under the <body> and the results is the same

Comment: I have never used `md-card-content`, but my guess is that you have to use `\n` within the textarea. If you have a plnkr then I can probably help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ newNewsForm?.value?.content.replace('\n','<br/>') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
          <textarea [(ngModel)]="val"></textarea>
          <p *ngFor="let subVal of vals">
            {{subVal}}
            <br/>
          </p>
        </div>
   `,
}) 
export class App {
    val: string = ""

    get vals(){
        return this.val.split("\n");
    }

    constructor() {}
}
```